# in-package sbcl

Tags: sbcl

In the REPL I do:
    * (defpackage :foo (:use common-lisp))
    * (in-package :foo)

```
#<PACKAGE "FOO">

* *package*

#<PACKAGE "FOO">
```

If I write the file:

try-package.lisp :

```
(defpackage :foo (:use common-lisp))
(in-package :foo)
```

then I load this file:

```
* (load "try-package")
T 
* *package*
#<PACKAGE "COMMON-LISP-USER">
```

Why I am always in COMMON-LISP-USER then I should be in FOO ?

Answer (score 0):

[`LOAD`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_load.htm)
*binds* `*PACKAGE*` (and also `*READTABLE*`) to the value it held
before loading the file, like this:

```
(let ((*package* *package*)
      (*readtable* *readtable*))
  ... ;; really load a file
)
```